# Upgrading MVC3 to MVC5 with ASPX/ASCX : issues with Inherits

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to upgrade an MVC3 to MVC5 project. I'm doing it from scratch (i.e. File new solution, then copying in code file by file). This project has ASPX/ASCX views.

My issue is that the Inherits lines in the ASPX dont allow strong typing i.e.

*`Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage"`* is OK but

*`Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<CCOK.Models.ViewModels.VMHperdet>"`* cannot resolve symbol "ViewModels"

Similarly *`Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<string>"`*  cannot resolve symbol ViewUserControl

I've tried creating an empty MVC project within the solution and the same things occur.

The Web.Config in the Views folder currently looks like this... (after copying in a few sample solutions to the problem). However, validateRequest, pageParserFilterType and UserControlBaseType all have intellisense warnings.

```
<configSections>
<sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
  <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
  <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
</sectionGroup>
</configSections>

<system.web.webPages.razor>
<host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />

<pages validateRequest="false" pageParserFilterType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewTypeParserFilter, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" userControlBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
  <controls>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" namespace="System.Web.Mvc" tagPrefix="mvc" />
  </controls>

    <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace="Kendo.Mvc.UI" />
    <add namespace="CCOK" />
    <add namespace="CCOK.Extensions" />
  </namespaces>
</pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

however, I get the same issues with a "stock" web.config

How do I get strongly typed ASPX/ASCX views working now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a day of missing the obvious, I noticed that I'm trying to define my winforms pages element inside system.web.webPAges.razor. The clue is in the word razor. The above pages element needs to be inside system.web (not web.webPages.razor) and then it all works a charm.